# Need help Regarding datetimepicker

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have taken a datetimePicker in C# winform. And I want to show data against the selected date. Basically what I did is,

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
i = 0;
cmd = "Select * from CourierReturn where ReturnDate = '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date+"'";
sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con);
sda.Fill(dst,"CourierReturn");
con.Open();
maxr = dst.Tables["CourierReturn"].Rows.Count;
navigate();
}
```

And in navigate()

```
private void navigate()
    {
        textBox1.Text = dst.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CourierNo"].ToString();
        textBox2.Text = dst.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BranchNo"].ToString();
        textBox3.Text = dst.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ReturnDate"].ToString();
        textBox4.Text = dst.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Reason"].ToString();
    }
```

I have done this coding above everything.

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\Aroona;Initial Catalog=ACSDatabase;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlDataAdapter sda;
    DataSet dst = new DataSet();
    string cmd;
    int maxr, i;
```

And in the Next Button, there is coding for Next, and so for previous, first and last.

when I change the date from the datetimepicker while the program is running, it does not change the values in textboxes. I tried this. `dst.Clear();` but it doesn't work, the way it has to. Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the navigate() method to make sure it is actually executing when you change the date? Also, you are opening your data connection after calling fill. You should move it to before the fill if you want to keep the connection open. If you don't need to keep it open then remove it completely and the fill method will open and close the connection automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cmd = "SELECT * FROM CourierReturn WHERE cast(ReturnDate as date) = '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+"'";
```

Comment: It doesn't work either :-( But can you please tell me why are you doing this cast(ReturnDate as date) ?

Comment: because if type is datetime, the date contains hour, minutes, second. with cast as date, the date only contains year,month and day.

put a breakpoint a this line "sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con);" and see cmd value, and paste here.

Comment: I found the solution! Actually, I was not closing the connection at the end. But, it worked after doing this and whenever the value of datetimepicker changed, it has to clear the data set first, then, it works perfectly. By the way, thanks for your help.